# How to find identity columns of a table in HSQLDB 1.8

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

In DB2 it can be done with the help of below query, but I can't find a way to do this in HSQLDB

```
SELECT COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE IDENTITY = 'Y' AND TABNAME='XXX'.
```

Below are the columns of the table SYSTEM_COLUMNS that I can see, I cannot determine which of these will indicate that it is a identity column

TYPE_SUB

TYPE_NAME

TABLE_SCHEM

TABLE_NAME

TABLE_CAT

SQL_DATETIME_SUB

SQL_DATA_TYPE

SOURCE_DATA_TYPE

SCOPE_TABLE

SCOPE_SCHEMA

SCOPE_CATLOG

REMARKS

ORDINAL_POSITION

NUM_PREC_RADIX

NULLABLE

IS_NULLABLE

DECIMAL_DIGITS

DATA_TYPE

COLUMN_SIZE

COLUMN_NAME

COLUMN_DEF

CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH

BUFFER_LENGTH

Comment: What do you mean by identity columns? Column(s) composing the primary key?

Comment: I mean for which there is column whose value is generated by database identifier generators like sequence,hilo,increment.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select column_name, 
       generation_expression, 
       is_generated, 
       is_identity, 
       identity_generation, 
       identity_start, 
       identity_increment 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name =  'XXX'
  and table_schema =  'PUBLIC'
  and is_identity = 'YES'
```

Comment: This does not wotk with hsqldb version 1.8, any help with that?

Comment: @AlokChandna: you should have mentioned that you are using a totally outdated HSQLDB version. The system view was named `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS` back then

Comment: Yes I got that, but it does not have an is_identity column

Comment: @AlokChandna: I have no idea then. That's too long ago.

Comment: Shouldn't `is_generated` mean the same thing?